# OpenID connect ADFS 2019 - authority invalid

Tags: c#, openid, adfs

Following the documentation example on microsoft for the adfs setup.
[ADFS microsoft setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/msal/adfs-msal-web-app-web-api)

I have the following application .Net 4.6.

startup.cs

```
    app.UseMyAppApiAuthentication(config);
```

in the class

```
  //setup OpenIdConnect Authentication
  var options = config.DependencyResolver.GetService<OpenIdConnectAuthenticationAndNotificationOptions>();
  app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(options);
```

In the options class i have

```
ClientId = configProvider.GetOpenIdConnectClientId();

Authority = configProvider.GetOpenIdConnectAuthority();

PostLogoutRedirectUri = configProvider.GetOpenIdConnectPostLogoutRedirectUri();

RedirectUri = configProvider.GetOpenIdConnectRedirectUri();

Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
{

    AuthorizationCodeReceived = authenticationNotificationProcessor.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
    AuthenticationFailed = authenticationNotificationProcessor.OnAuthenticationFailed
};
```

where authority is

```
public string GetOpenIdConnectAuthority()
{
    var instance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["moto:AADInstance"];
    var tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["moto:Tenant"];
    return String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, instance, tenant);
}
```

In the webconfig, I have the clientid and client secret set, I have the AADinstance set and tenant is blank.
If I put in the ADFS URI. I get the following error:

[image: Authority error]

Now if I edit the AADinstance and add /.well-known/Openid-configuration i get a different error...

[image: Unable to create]

I have also changed the config and removed authority and replace with "MetadataAddress" still no change.
What do I need todo to resolve this issue?

Note: if I change the redirect URI to something different when running the app, I manage to get to the adfs login screen with the error that there is a mismatch with the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to open a support case since it needs deep troubleshooting in order to isolate the issue.